# Swapping Images in menu using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time posting here so be gentle.  I'm trying to create a menu for a web site using javascript.  I want to click on an item in my menu and swap images.  This part is easy and working fine.  Where I'm falling down is I want the previous items in my menu to revert back to their original source image.  This would be simple if they all used the same images, but they all have their own unique images.  Hope I'm explaining myself ok.

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the minimal JS/jQ, CSS, HTML to reproduce the *view*. To add code click the Snippet icon in the editor.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to read our [ask] page to help you formulate a great question.  You are much more likely to get a good answer from the community if you put some effort into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function to store information in an element for later retrieval.

Before you change the image's `src`, you store the current `src` so that you can then use it to restore the `src` when you want to change it back.
Example:

```js
// When a menu item's link is clicked
$('.menu-item a').on('click', function(e) {
  // Prevent the link firing
  e.preventDefault();
  // Grab the menu item
  var self = $(this).parent();

  // find our image
  var img = self.find('img');
  // make sure we're not double changing
  if (!img.hasClass('changed')) {
    // Store our existing src in a the jQuery data
    img.data('original-src', img.attr('src'));
    // Set a new src
    img.attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/g/20/20/');
    // Add a class so we know what's changed
    img.addClass('changed');
  }

  // Search for existing changed images
  self.siblings().find('img.changed').each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    // Remove the changed tag
    img.removeClass('changed');
    // Restore the src
    img.attr('src', img.data('original-src'));
  });

});
```

```css
#my-menu {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="my-menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" role="presentation" />
      One
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" role="presentation" />
      Two
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" role="presentation" />
      Three
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: With the limited explanation of what the OP wants, I'd say this is a good answer +1

Comment: Yep, sorry for the horrible wording.  This is a great answer.  thanks again!